# How to set Saturday as first day of week in Power BI reports?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, dayofweek, week-number, powerbi-custom-visuals

I made a table with daily values. I need to show it in a weekly chart in which the first day of the week is Saturday.
How can I change the first day of week in Power BI?

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround that will set your axis to categorical - hope its helpful:
You could create static table by entering data like follows-

```
Col1      Col2
Saturday   1
Sunday     2
Monday     3
Tuesday    4
Wednesday  5
Thursday   6
Friday     7
```

Create a relationship between the date table and this new table.
Use Col1 from this table in you visual as the date.
Sort the column by col2.

This will only work/be useful if you want to show 1 week's worth of data or aggregating by day of the week.

Comment: Thank you ver much. I think it cannot be used for more than one week data. For example if there are 7 weeks, and we sort them based on col2, it shows all 1 first, then all 2, and ...

Comment: @Pardis Bagheri Yes this is a drawback of this workaround it works if you are showing one week or aggregating individual days - I have added this to the answer - you could add a week column to your original data WEEKNUM(<date>, <return_type>) and then drill down with both the week day and week value